# how can i sum the size of this tensors?

Tags: pytorch, sum, tensor, torch

I have different sizes or shapes for each tensor like

```
torch.Size([1, 12, 1000])
torch.Size([1, 12, 1000])
torch.Size([1, 10, 1000])
torch.Size([1, 11, 1000])
torch.Size([1, 11, 1000])
torch.Size([1, 15, 1000])
torch.Size([1, 10, 1000])
....
```

and need to be like `torch.Size((12+12+10+11+11+15+ .... ),1000)`

my code is

```
def extract():
     for y in sentences:
            tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(y)
            indexed_tokens = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenized_text)        
            tokens_tensor = torch.tensor([indexed_tokens])
            model.eval()
            outputs = model(tokens_tensor)
            hidden_states = outputs[2]
            my_tensor = torch.cat([hidden_states[i] for i in [-1,-2,-3,-4]], dim=-1)
     return my_tensor
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate them:

```
tensors = [t1, t2, t3, ...]
result = torch.cat(tensors, dim=1)

# result.size(): torch.Size([1, 12+12+10+..., 1000])
```

If you also want to remove the first dimension, as it has size `1`:

```
result = result.squeeze()
# result.size(): torch.Size([12+12+10+..., 1000])
```

Comment: thanks a lot for replying . i provided my code which my_tensor returns every time different shape . so excuse me should i try your code after the my_tesnor line ?

Comment: this line `my_tensor = torch.cat([hidden_states[i] for i in [-1,-2,-3,-4]], dim=-1)` is correct. You only need to change dim argument to `1`.

Comment: thanks but i got `weight shape torch.Size([10, 1000])` for the total as i checked it by     `print("Total",my_tensor.shape)` before return statement

Comment: can you print the shape of each tensor in `hidden_states`?

Comment: i tried to `print(hidden_states.shape)` but got `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Comment: you have to cycle through each element of the tuple and print the shape of each elelment